# Improving speed of varchar(max) queries

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-express, varchar

I have a database in SQL Express with about 200k entries in this format.

| name | value | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toronto | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| Zürich | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| Frauenfeld | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| Berlin | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| Frankfurt am Main | abc | abc | abc | abc |

The column "name"  is from the type: varchar(max)

Now when I want to find the entry with the name 'Frankfurt am Main'
`SELECT * FROM networkanalyzer.dbo.Orte WHERE dbo.Orte.name = 'Frankfurt am Main';`

It takes wayy to long. It takes about 200 - 400ms to find the exact entry. And I have to do many of these queries!
Is there a possibility to improve the performance?

Thank so much!
Severin

Comment: Presumably the data type is `varchar(max)` for a reason - are you having to cater for more than 8k of data per value?

Comment: Your query is not valid syntax for tsql. Perhaps you are missing a join? And make life easier for everyone - define aliases for every table and use them when referencing any column.

Comment: For suggestions on improving performance you will need to include details of the table schema, index and constraints plus the *actual* execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Oh, and a valid query!

Comment: I mean 200 ms is still less than a second? The one thing you could do is figure out if MAX can be changed to varchar(n). Using MAX is not necessary for names, even if the name in question is Tikki Tikki Tembo-No so Rembo-Chari Bari Ruchi-Pip Peri Pembo

Comment: An index would help, but you cannot create one on a column wider than 900 bytes. And why do you need to do "many of these queries", perhaps you can batch them by joining a Table Valued Parameter?

Comment: Sorry! Now the query is correct and working!